# How to animate A curve segment?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

How can I animate the position of a Bézier curve segment as shown in the images below?

[image: Beginning of animation]
[image: End of animation]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can 'Hook' the control point of the curve by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while in edit mode, with the point of the curve you want to move selected and choosing 'Hook to new object'. Adding the hook via this shortcut is just a quick way of setting up the hook modifier, which will be present on the curve after the shortcut is pressed.

This will create an 'Empty' object which can be animated. The control point of the curve will be parented to the position of the empty and will follow the empty wherever you animate it to.

[image]

Comment: it might be obvious to some but you can add multiple hooks to a single curve and then animate each independently. Amazingly powerful.

Comment: In the above solution I see the curve take an S shape instead of a smooth C shape (even in Blender 3.5 with control points set to auto). Any workaround for that?

Answer (score 22):

To directly animate a curve's segment, without hooks or shapekeys, you can enable the [AninAll](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/AnimAll) addon. It allows you to create keyframes for each control point.

[image]

Comment: animall is now part of the default blender add-ons. You can enable it in the settings window.

Answer (score 15):

Another way you could do this is with a shape key:

[image: Demonstration of using a shape key to create animation]

Steps:

1. In Object Mode, select the *Data* tab of the Properties panel. Under *Shape Keys*, create two keys: the basis and a key for your animation.
2. With the second key selected, enter Edit Mode and perform your transformations.
3. Animate the *Value* of the shape key as desired.

Neither this method nor the hook method is inherently superior to the other.
Here are some of the advantages and disadvantages of this method:

- **Advantage:** You can create more complex transformations. For example, you could turn a sphere into a gear by scaling out every other vertex, and then animate a single shape key.
- **Disadvantage:** You have less control. With a hooked empty, you can control the empty's location with all the standard animation tools—including linking it to a path, using constraints, etc. With a shape key, you can only animate a factor value that linearly interpolates "to" and "from."
- **Advantage:** You can easily combine multiple shape keys. For example, on a circular path, you could have a "Gear" shape key (as described above) and also a "Pinch" shape key that squishes the path along some axis. It's easy to combine these with shape keys, and less so with hooks (you would have to fiddle around with the *Force* values).

As usual, you should know your options, consider the situation, and decide which method is best in that particular case.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in 2.8 final. Shapekeys no longer seem to care about curves as far as I was able to tell. (Hopefully I am wrong, and am just doing it incorrectly.)