# Let text follow animated beziercurve

Tags: text-object, bezier-curves

I have created a 3D bezier curve.
In order to animate that bezier curve I have added hooked the curve with empties (ctrl+h used: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21234 )

Now I have selected my text and set up a Child Of constraint on the text and set the target to my BezierCurve ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26109 ).

Now my problem:
when I animate my bezier curve, I now have to grab the empties and move them around. The problem is that the bezier curve stays at its location, resulting in that the text doesn't move.

I always want that my text follows in the center of my curve at a fixed distance.
But doesn't seems to work with the ctrl+h and child of constraint.

[image]

This is the **result that I want** after moving the curve. I moved the empties and **manually** set the text at the position, as the text didn't follow the curve by itself:

[image]

(note: I'm not so experienced yet with blender)

**Update:** The file I have so far:

[image]

**Update 2:** for now I've added a bezier curve, extruded it over the x-axis so that it doubles in length and has 3 'control points' (start, middle and end). Next I've added 3 hooks (ctrl+h) which generate 3 empties.
After this I've added my text and added 2 constraints which attach on the middle Empty (hook): a childof and limit distance.
Now I  can animate by keyframing the 3 empties and dragging the empties to other locations. By dragging the empties the curve moves and the text also follows the middle empty.
Could not find a better solution for now...

Comment: This might not be possible with constraints... you might have to use an armature. Sorry I can't be more help than that...