# Fill area behind animated line

Tags: animation

I'm animating lines.
Similar to this: [image] ([Let text follow animated beziercurve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57302/let-text-follow-animated-beziercurve))

Now I would like to fill in the area behind the curve.
Similar to this:

[image]

so that if I move my line than the filled area also moves.
(It would be ideal if there is a gradient that the color is stronger near the line and fades out to transparent when further away.).

any suggestions on how to start this?

Comment: "fill the area _behind the link_" ? I'm not sure to get it...

Comment: sorry, typo.:-)

Comment: So you'd like to animate transition between that change - filled and unfilled areas? Or just changing amount of area curve can fill?  You could increase area filled with curve by adjusting Offset value of the Curve object in its properties > Geometry scroll. But it will "fill" everywhere around, not just some areas.

Comment: see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oabxoP_jVM 
I want to move a line and also fill the "red" area behind that line. So that if I move my line that the area also moves. I don't know if it is possible but maybe I can create an outline of curves and fill the shape? And for the fill add a linear color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I got what you mean, you could toggle cyclic (ALT-C) on the 2D curve in edit mode, to get a fill. In Blender there's no concept of "object border" but you could use freestyle to obtain something usable maybe.

Here is the overall setup from which you could start...

[image]

for the fill, you should be able to use a "Blend" texture type using also transparency, see second image example

[image]