# Unable to pose rigged hose or keyframe it

Tags: rigging

I'm new to rigging, so hopefully these errors aren't glaring :)  I'm trying to pose this hose and keyframe it, but the hose warps when I move the bones (I used a curve with IK spline for the bones).  Also, I'm not able to keyframe it.

Here's the resting pose:

[image]

Here's what happens when I try to move it:

[image]

**I've attached the .blend**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/how-to-animate-a-curve-segment/21235#21235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, bezier curve control points themselves are not keyframe-able.  You can, however, make a "hook" to those control points by selecting them in edit mode and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.  The hooks created this way are keyframe-able, and should give you the level of control you are looking for.

Comment: You can also use the Anim-All addon. It will allow you to keyframe the control points of curves.

Comment: Awesome ctrl + h totally worked.  Still figuring out Anim-All too.  But how do I deal with the deformation of the hose?