# Morph Text from Horizontal to Curve above

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, text-object

How is the best way to morph text from a Horizontal to an Arc above it?  When I add the Curve Modifier to my Text it instantly get transformed.  Thus, I am unable to lock (keyframe) the start.  Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape Keys!

I discovered the Shape Keys for the Curve and used them to animate my Curve.

Here is a more complete answer: [How to animate A curve segment?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21233/how-to-animate-a-curve-segment)